# GE oven Burner On light on even though burners are off and cold - can I sleep with this issue overnight?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light, oven

It is midnight here and my apartment on-call techs are not answering... I am not strong enough to move the oven to unplug it myself. Is it safe to sleep with this issue overnight? Burners have been off for hours and this light is still on.

Answer (score 3):

Probably will be fine (especially if the controls are off).  But if you want to be sure, find the circuit breaker for your stove and turn off power there.  My in-laws had an electric flat-top stove of recent vintage that after a while that light indicating a hot burner never was off and they never worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to worry about, IF this is an electric range, i.e., the oven and the surface burners are electric. Is it?

Is this the illumination light inside the oven? There is a manually operated switch on the outside and a second switch connected to the oven door. If either switch is on (closed), then the light inside should be on.  It has nothing to do with the surface burners. This oven light automatically comes on when the oven door is opened. If the oven door is closed and the exterior switch is off, and the light inside the oven is on, then one of the two switches is faulty.

Comment: It's likely not the light in the oven.  Flat-surface electric stoves often have an indicator light underneath the flat cooktop to let the user know that a burner may be hot, since it might not be visually obvious that the surface may still be hot.